# Eliminar una fila de un Array bidimensional en JAVA

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente arreglo Bidimensional llamado `info`:

```
Laura,9,8,10,10,10,10,20  
Pedro,10,50,10,35,10,10,90  
Luis,10,60,10,70,10,41,17  
Mario,10,10,10,43,10,10,23  
Blanca,10,89,41,10,10,85,17
```

¿Cuál seria el código para poder eliminar cualquier fila?
Por ejemplo, toda la fila 2. Se que está en la posición `info[2][0]` sin embargo, no sé cual sería el código para eliminar la fila.

El código del cual dispongo solo recorre el arreglo:

```
for (int x=0; x < info.length; x++) {  
     for (int y=0; y < info[x].length; y++)  
          System.out.print(info[x][y]+"\t");     
     System.out.println("\n");  
}
```

Investigando solo he encontrado que al momento de eliminar el *array*, solo sustituyen los valores por ceros, pero eso no es lo que necesito, si no eliminar la fila por completo y re-dimensionar el *array*.

Comment: Hola @Alberto. Podrías mostrar lo que has intentado? Indica lo que has probado y donde te has atascado o donde te falla. Has hecho otra pregunta sobre este ejercicio donde tampoco has puesto lo que has intentado. Por favor, lee [ask] y edita tu pregunta para hacerla aceptable para el sitio.

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar. Es cierto, ya previamente había preguntado, y con ayuda de ustedes he podido adaptar el código y solucionar el problema. Este sería el último paso que me queda por resolver.

Comment: Lo dicho, como has podido observar, aquí se ayuda a la gente pero hace falta que demuestres cierto esfuerzo. Por eso te digo, hace falta que añadas lo que has intentado y podremos ver como ayudarte. Ánimo!

Comment: Partiendo de la base que tienes, puedo darte una idea. Crea una matriz totalmente nueva con los valores que quieres. Espero que te sirva la idea.

Comment: ¿Sólo vas a eliminar una fila o no lo sabes de antemano? Yo crearía una nueva matriz con la nueva dimensión e iría rellenándola excepto la fila que no quieres (con un if) recorriendo la original.

Comment: Con arrays normales no puedes eliminar las posiciones ya que son elementos de tamaño fijo y no dinámicos. Te recomiendo usar la clase ArrayList, que vienen siendo arrays dinámicos y hacen lo mismo pero son más flexibles y gestionan la memoria automáticamente, permitiéndote eliminar posiciones concretas y reorganizándose de manera automática. En tu caso podrías usar un ArrayList que contenga otros ArrayList para así tener una estructura que simule un array bidimensional,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes llamar a un método que mediante un `for` recorra el array bidimensional (también llamado "matriz") y vaya creando en cada vuelta una nueva matriz clonada de la tuya, que compruebe la fila que quieres eliminar y no añada dicha fila en el clon de tu matriz.

Te he creado un ejemplo funcional que puedes ejecutar desde este enlace (pulsa en Execute arriba a la izquierda)

http://tpcg.io/vlJMvF

En mi ejemplo, la matriz es de 3 filas y 3 columnas, porque me daba pereza meter todos tus datos.

Saludos

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda!!!!! estoy estudiando tu ejemplo. De verdad, gracias :)

Comment: @Juanant tambien podrias embeber (agregar) el codigo o fracmento de el, en tu respuesta, ya que con el tiempo los enlaces tienden a romperse, y si eso llega a suceder por lo menos los demas usuarios podran ver el fracmento de codigo que embebiste.

Comment: He estudiado el código que me proporcionaste Juanant, me ha servido de mucho. Note que puedo eliminar cualquier fila de "n" dimensiones, siempre y cuando la fila a borrar, no sea igual a "n". Es decir, si tengo un arreglo de 10 filas y 3 columnas, podré borrar hasta la fila 9, una vez que le ingreso la 10 me arroja error. Yo me supongo porque después de la fila 10 no hay nada, por ende no sustituye ningún valor. ¿Podrias apoyarme en ese sentido? Gracias!!!

Comment: Juanant, creo que ya lo solucione. Simplemente pongo una nueva opción con if, donde detecte que si el usuario ha ingresado el equivalente al número de líneas del arreglo. Hacer un ciclo for donde me lea todo el arreglo, menos el último  :) GRACIAS !!!!

Answer (score 2):

No se puede *redimensionar* un array, el tamaño es fijo una vez creado. Lo normal en estos casos casos es usar una estructura de datos que te permita esa flexibilidad (Por ejemplo usar listas (la interfaz `java.util.List`, con las clases `java.util.ArrayList` o `java.util.LinkedList`).

Otra opción es tener una variable aparte que indique el número de filas usadas e ir recolocándolas en el array conforme se necesite.

Para borrar de un array como el que presentas, podrías hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
String [][] info = new Object[][] {
    {"Laura,""9","8","10","10","10","10","20}",
    {"Pedro","10","50","10","35","10","10","90"},
    {"Luis","10","60","10","70","10","41","17"},
    {"Mario","10","10","10","43","10","10","23"},
    {"Blanca","10","89","41","10","10","85","17"}
}

//eliminemos la fila 2

static void eliminarFila(String[][] info,int f) {
    for (int i=f; i < info.length; i++) {
        info[i]=info[i+1]; //movemos el resto de filas a la posición anterior
    }
    info[info.length - 1] =null; //la última posición queda vacía
}
```

Otra oción sería crear un nuevo array, descartando el antiguo:

```
static String[][] eliminarFila(String[][] info,int f) {
    if (info.length==0) {
        return info; //ya está vacío
    } 

    String [][] resultado= new String[info.length-1][];
    for (int i=0; i < f; i++) {
        resultado[i]=info[i]; //simplemente copiamos las filas anteriores
    }
    for (int i=f; i < info.length; i++) {
        resultado[i]=info[i+1]; //ahora copiamos las posteriores
    }
    return resultado
}
```